# Flutter - type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<String>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting this error: `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<String>'`

```
void main() async {
  hello();
}

Future<String> hello() async {
  return dynamicHello(); // error : type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<String>'
  return dynamicHello().then((value) => value); // working well
}

Future<dynamic> dynamicHello() async {
  return 'HELLO';
}
```

can someone please explain me the difference between `return dynamicHello()` and `return dynamicHello().then((value) => value)` above code

I checked the signature on Future is Future then(FutureOr action(T value), {Function onError}). However, I did not clearly understand why "return dynamicHello()" works normally if I make `Future<String> dynamicHello()`.

Answer (score 2):

You must return both Future are `String` or `dynamic`. try below code hope its help to you.

Refer **`Future`** class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html)

**Both are `String`**

```
void main() async {
  hello();
}

Future<String> hello() async {
  return dynamicHello(); // happen : type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<String>'
  return dynamicHello().then((value) => value); // working well
}

Future<String> dynamicHello() async {
  return 'HELLO';
}
```

Or **Both are `dynamic`**

```
void main() async {
  hello();
}

Future<dynamic> hello() async {
  return dynamicHello(); // happen : type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<String>'
  return dynamicHello().then((value) => value); // working well
}

Future<dynamic> dynamicHello() async {
  return 'HELLO';
}
```

or

```
void main() async {
  hello();
}

Future  hello() async {
  return dynamicHello(); // happen : type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<String>'
  return dynamicHello().then((value) => value); // working well
}

Future dynamicHello() async {
  return 'HELLO';
}
```